# Set up mail.mydomain.com to point to dedicated server

Tags: email, dns, server, mx-record

I currently have a domain name which is set to point to Amazon Cloudfront's nameservers. I also have a dedicated server which uses WHM/cPanel that I want to use for all mail.

On Amazon:

- The A record for the domain is set to point to the server IP
- The MX record is set up as well

On Server:

- I have an A record for "mail" that points to the server IP

However, when I log into cPanel webmail, I can send mail but cannot receive it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Some type of routing issue I am assuming? When I send an email via Gmail to myemail@mydomain.com, it does not bounce back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by changing the MX record from **mydomain.com.** to **mail.mydomain.com.** and then having the A record for **mail** point to the server IP.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more with  screenshot maybe?